# How to put a space between arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array

Sorry if I'm not specific, but I have my code in working order, but I do not know how to separate the two different array outputs(?). Here's my code:

```
package code;
public class ArrayPrinter{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int FirstArray[][] = { {5, 6, 7, 8,} , {2, 4, 6, 8} , {8, 7, 9, 1} , {3, 5, 1, 2} };


        printarray(FirstArray);

    }

        public static void printarray(int a[][]) {

            for( int row = 0 ; row < a.length ; row++ )  {
                for ( int column = 0 ; column < a[row].length ; column++ ) {

                    System.out.print( a[row][column] + " ");

                }


            System.out.println();

            }


            int SecondArray[][] = { {1, 2} , {3, 4, 5} , {6} , {7, 8, 9} };

            printarray1(SecondArray);


        }

public static void printarray1(int b[][]) {

            for( int row = 0 ; row < b.length ; row++ )  {
                for ( int column = 0 ; column < b[row].length ; column++ ) {

                    System.out.print( b[row][column] + " ");

                }


            System.out.println();
    }

   }

}
```

Here is the output:

5 6 7 8

2 4 6 8

8 7 9 1

3 5 1 2

1 2

3 4 5

6

7 8 9

Here is what I want it to look like

5 6 7 8

2 4 6 8

8 7 9 1

3 5 1 2

(well it wont let me add spaces, but I want these two sperated)

1 2

3 4 5

6

7 8 9

Help please.

Comment: Are you saying you want an extra blank line between 3512 and 12?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: So is that an extra new line at the end of every printed 2D array?

Comment: I added an extra line just in the post because whenever I didn't add an extra line, it made the rows come out jumbled together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an extra System.out.println() after the outermost for loop like...

```
public static void printarray(int a[][]) {

        for( int row = 0 ; row < a.length ; row++ )  {
            for ( int column = 0 ; column < a[row].length ; column++ ){

                System.out.print( a[row][column] + " ");

            }


            System.out.println();

        }

        System.out.println();

        int SecondArray[][] = { {1, 2} , {3, 4, 5} , {6} , {7, 8, 9} };

        printarray1(SecondArray);


}
```

Also your two print functions look identical and could be combined.